# Link pairs of type bounds together in Python

Tags: python, repository-pattern

I am trying to create an abstract repository class so that I can reduce drastically the length of my boilerplate code. Meanwhile, to do so, I would need to link the bounds of `Entity` to a certain `Domain` (Like when using Pick in Typescript) in order to raise mypy attention such `Missing positional arguments`. Is it possible to do so in Python ?

```
"""
Generic Repository
"""
from src.Managers.session import SessionManager
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query
from src.User.models.TermsOfUse import TermsOfUseModel, TermsOfUse
from src.User.models.User import UserModel, User

entity_bound = Union[UserModel, TermsOfUseModel]
domain_bound = Union[User, TermsOfUse]

Entity = TypeVar('Entity', bound=entity_bound)
Domain = TypeVar('Domain', bound=domain_bound)
SpecificException = TypeVar('SpecificException', bound=Exception)


class RepoPattern(Generic[Entity, Domain, SpecificException]):
    """
    Repository Pattern.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        entity: type[Entity],
        domain: type[Domain],
        exception: type[SpecificException],
        session_context: SessionManager
            ):

        self._entity = entity
        self._domain = domain
        self._exception = exception
        self._session_context = session_context

    @property
    def session_context(self) -> SessionManager:
        return self._session_context

    def add(self, domain: Domain) -> None:
        """
        Add a new domain object.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param domain: domain object.

        Returns:
        ----
            Domain
        """
        entity = self._get_entity_from_domain(domain)
        self._session_context.add(entity)

    def modify(self, domain: Domain) -> None:
        """
        Add a new domain object.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param domain: domain object.

        Returns:
        ----
            Domain
        """
        assert domain.id

        query = self._find_by_id_query(domain.id)
        entity = self._find_first_record(query)
        entity.reset(domain.to_dict())
        self._session_context.modify(entity)

    def remove(self, domain: Domain) -> None:
        """
        Remove a domain object.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param domain: domain object.

        Returns:
        ----
            Domain
        """
        assert domain.id

        query = self._find_by_id_query(domain.id)
        entity = self._find_first_record(query)
        self._session_context.remove(entity)

    def find_by_id(self, id: int) -> Domain:
        """
        Find a domain object by id.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param id: id of the entity.

        Returns:
        ----
            Domain
        """
        query = self._find_by_id_query(id)
        return self._find_first_domain(query)

    def _find_by_id_query(self, id: int) -> Query[Entity]:
        """
        Find a domain object by id.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param id: id of the entity.

        Returns:
        ----
            Query[Entity]
        """
        query = self._entity.query.filter_by(id=id)
        return query

    def _find_first_domain(self, query: Query[Entity]) -> Domain:
        """
        Find the first domain object.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param query: query.

        Returns:
        ----
            Domain
        """
        record = self._find_first_record(query)
        domain = self._get_domain_from_entity(record)
        return domain

    def _find_all(self, query: Query[Entity]) -> list[Domain]:
        """
        Find all domain objects.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param query: query.

        Returns:
        ----
            list[Domain]
        """
        records = self._find_all_records(query)
        return [
            self._get_domain_from_entity(record) for record in records
            ]

    def _find_first_record(self, query: Query[Entity]) -> Entity:
        """
        Find the first user record.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param query: query.

        Returns:
        ----
            Entity
        """

        record = query.first()

        if not record:
            raise self._exception()

        return record

    def _find_all_records(self, query: Query[Entity]) -> list[Entity]:
        """
        Find all records.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param query: query.

        Returns:
        ----
            list[Entity]
        """

        records = query.all()
        return records

    def _get_domain_from_entity(self, entity: Entity) -> Domain:
        """
        Get the entity to domain.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param entity: entity used.

        Returns:
        ----
            Domain
        """
        return self._domain.from_dict(entity.to_dict())

    def _get_entity_from_domain(self, domain: Domain) -> Entity:
        """
        Get the domain to entity.

        Parameters:
        ----
            :param domain: domain used.

        Returns:
        ----
            Entity
        """

        return self._entity(**domain.to_dict())
```

---

Edit: I want mypy to raise these kind of errors: `Argument 1 to "reset" of "UserModel" has incompatible type "TermsOfUseDomainDict"; expected "UserDomainDict"  [arg-type] mypy(error)` while instantiating the repository pattern like that:

```
repo = RepoPattern(
   UserModel,
   TermsOfUse,
   UserNotFoundException,
   SessionManager()
)
```

Meanwhile I cannot bound my generic types using a simple Union as:

```
entity_bound = Union[UserModel, TermsOfUseModel]
domain_bound = Union[User, TermsOfUse]
```

What I need is picking a domain type bound given an entity type.
For instance: When selecting a UserModel type as an entity type. I would automatically select a User domain type in the repository.

Comment: Could you please provide an example you want to prevent?

Comment: Isn't my answer sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inherit from the `RepoPattern` for each entity-domain pair, you can specialize the `TypeVar`s in the derived class. Also, do not hard code the `entity_bound` and `domain_bound` in the abstract base class module, and consider working with something like abstract `Entity` and `Domain` classes. I also didn't understand why you made the `SpecificException` type variable since it doesn't appear in the class interface at all. With this idea in mind, the code could be something similar to this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type
from entity import Entity
from domain import Domain

TEntity = TypeVar("TEntity", bound=Entity)
TDomain = TypeVar("TDomain", bound=Domain)

class RepositoryBase(Generic[TEntity, TDomain]):
    def __init__(
        self, entity_type: Type[TEntity], domain_type: Type[TDomain]
    ) -> None:
        ...

class UserRepository(RepositoryBase[UserModel, User]):
    ...
```

But if you prefer to keep your solution, you can `overload` the `__init__` function to only accept specific combinations:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type, overload
from entity import Entity
from domain import Domain

TEntity = TypeVar("TEntity", bound=Entity)
TDomain = TypeVar("TDomain", bound=Domain)

class Repository(Generic[TEntity, TDomain]):
    @overload
    def __init__(
        self: Repository[UserModel, User],
        entity_type: Type[UserModel],
        domain_type: Type[User],
    ) -> None:
        pass

    @overload
    def __init__(
        self: Repository[TermOfUseModel, TermOfUse],
        entity_type: Type[TermOfUseModel],
        domain_type: Type[TermOfUse],
    ) -> None:
        pass

    def __init__(self, entity_type, domain_type) -> None:
        ...


Repository(UserModel, User)
Repository(TermOfUseModel, TermOfUse)
Repository(
    UserModel, TermOfUse
)  # error: Argument 2 to "Repository" has incompatible type "type[TermOfUse]"; expected "type[User]"  [arg-type]
```

You should avoid annotating the actual `__init__` implementation because the union of two overloads does not cover all combinations. Instead, annotate the `self` variable in the overloads to guide Mypy in deducing `TypeVar`s.

**Some side notes:**

- Avoid importing modules from the `src` directory, as your imports will not work when the code is installed.
- I couldn't find any public interface with the `Entity` type variable usage in your code. Consider removing it from the type variables and using a runtime mapping or function to create or work with entities from the domain or domain type.
- Mapping between similar or related objects in different layers is not the repository's responsibility. Consider using auto-mappers like [py-automapper](https://github.com/anikolaienko/py-automapper) or [object-mapper](https://github.com/marazt/object-mapper). Alternatively, you can implement your specific mappers or place the mapping logic in the class on the outer layer.
- Mypy itself doesn't support [Type mappings](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1273).
- Alternatively, you might find the Active Record pattern and its implementations in Python more suitable for your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I knew what I wanted to do was a bit stretched but hoped for a moment that mypy could help. Anyway, I am going to stick to my boilerplate code instead of using automappers as I don’t have that many properties to set.